# Using Riot games api to retrieve data during champion select

Tags: python, riot-games-api

I am trying to build a small third-party software, for me and my friends, similar to op.gg or blitz.gg

I have been exploring riot games API for a few hours now; however, I can not seem to find a get request to retrieve my teammates' names during champion select.
I considered retrieving them from chat, but can not find a get request for chat either.

How does other third-party software do it exactly if riot API does not provide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer probably came too late, but i will explain how they do it, there is a "hidden" API in league named [LCU](https://riot-api-libraries.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lcu.html) , they make the calls there, if you want to get champ select data you should call here: /lol-champ-select/v1/session
i insert a guide that is really useful [to get started](https://hextechdocs.dev/getting-started-with-the-lcu-api/).

Comment: It's not late. Thank you so much for the answer and the article.

Answer (score 0):

If it's during champion select website like op.gg and porofessor.gg ask you to copy chat joined message and then they do api calls to gather informations on your teammates with SUMMONER-V4

Gif that explains : https://cdn2.porofessor.gg/img/pregame-explanation.mp4

After you can have informations during live game with the SPECTATOR-V4 endpoint but there is no endpoint provided by riot games api for champion select unfortunately

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am aware that the websites ask for the chat log. However, their desktop apps (op.gg app, porofessor, blitz, etc ..) don't ask for anything. I considered using OCR, but was trying to find something easier.